# Find a mystery process which is killing my process

Tags: java, linux, unix, process, signals

Let's say I have some process - in this case a Java process, launched by ant.  I find that randomly something is sending this Java process SIGTERM.  It could be the process sending that signal to itself, or it could be something else.

I have eliminated most of the obvious causes (oom killer, parent process killing child, etc), but I really want to find out *who* is sending this process SIGTERM.  Any way to trace this behavior at the OS or process level?

Comment: I don't know if java has some native or wrapped access to `sigaction()` but when called with the SA_SIGINFO field the pid and real uid will be passed to the handler you set.  You might be able to catch your culprit that way.

Comment: Yeah, if only it was C.  Java does offer some limited signal handling, but no access to the pid/uid of the sender.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a signal handler in your java program via JNI, see [interface java with C timer library using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616362/interface-java-with-c-timer-library-using-jni) for an example of that (catches SIGALRM, but should be easily adaptable). Beware of some problems when messing with signals in java, though (see http://nerds-central.blogspot.de/2011/04/java-jvm-jni-and-signal-handling.html ): Basically you need to take care to chain your signal handlers to the existing and not to replace them.

If you suspect human interaction another approach might be to modify the `kill` executable on the machine where this mystery happens. Replace it with a shell script that logs who is logged in, its PID and parent PID and then calls the original kill.

I put something together that works on my PC: https://gist.github.com/4183018

Answer (score 1):

If you have dtrace available (Solaris, OS X, FreeBSD), this simple Dtrace script would easily detect the mystery process:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -qCs

#include <signal.h>

proc:::signal-send
/ args[2] == SIGTERM && args[1]->pr_fname == "java" /
{
    printf("Process %d (%s) run by uid %d is sending SIGTERM to java (pid %d)\n",
            pid, execname, uid, args[1]->pr_pid);
}
```

Comment: This is old but, potentially solves a similar issue I'm having; Any idea how to get this to compile on MacOS Ventura 13.6.2? 
`In file included from /dev/fd/6:3:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/.../usr/include/signal.h:61:
/Applications/Xcode.app/.../usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:81:2: warning: "Unsupported compiler detected" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Unsupported compiler detected"
 ^
1 warning generated.
dtrace: failed to compile script bin/sigtrace: "/Applications/Xcode.app/.../usr/include/mach/arm/_structs.h", line 498: syntax error near "__uint128_t"`

Comment: @EdRandall What do you do exactly to get this error message?

Comment: Ran your script on MacOS 13.6.2 exactly as-given except changed "java" to "sleep" (in order to test killing a sleep command)

Comment: @EdRandall I have no MacOS machine to test but according to the error message, the preprocessor is unhappy with something. Given the fact I only use it to get SIGTERM value, you can try removing the `#include` line and replacing SIGTERM with its actual value, presumably `15`. There might be other issues on MacOS, like [SIP](https://www.shogan.co.uk/devops/dtrace-dtruss-an-alternative-to-strace-on-macos/).

Comment: thanks for your help, indeed after replacing the `#include` with `#define SIGTERM 15` I now get a SIP error `dtrace: failed to compile script bin/sigtrace: line 6: probe description proc:::signal-send does not match any probes. System Integrity Protection is on`.    Instead I'm now trying [Objective-See ProcessMonitor](https://objective-see.org/products/utilities.html).

Comment: @EdRandall You gave up on using dtrace? Disabling temporarily SIP is not an option?

Comment: This is a work laptop with various corp security monitoring, don't intend to trigger some InfoSec flag.  I'm already down a rabbithole chasing this problem I shouldn't have.  If ProcessMonitor can tell me what I need to know then great, if not, I'll be back... (FWIW, my money is on the corp security malware being the source of the SIGTERM)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're getting SIGTERM signal? 
Have you tried to use linux `strace` command and see what signal do you have. I'm not sure it will show you a pid of the process that sent the signal though.

Comment: Yes, we can see we are getting sigterm based on the return value - 143 = 128 + SIGTERM.